# Heroku pipeline - identical code on staging & production but production breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am new to Rails (and Heroku) and have been using a pipeline for deployment. I assume both environments are identical - I use one for staging and one for deployment.

Staging works perfectly but when promoting code to production it breaks. This file seems to be the issue but I can't see why - any idea?

```html
<div class="row invite-friends" data-page-id-invite-friend=''>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <%= render 'shared/user_info'%>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 well">
    <h3>Plans</h3>
    <p>Choose a plan to help you reach your goals. All plans deliver structured content from our team of experienced trainers to your feed every day.</p>
    <hr />
    


<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  
<% @diets.each do |diet| %> 

    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading<%=diet.id%>">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%=diet.id%>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<%=diet.id%>">
          <%= diet.title%> <span class="caret"></span>
           </a>
      </h4>
          <div class="plans_meta"> 
            Rating: <%= content_with_emoji( "" * diet.rating.to_i) %>
            <br>
            Difficulty: <%= content_with_emoji("" * diet.difficulty.to_i) %>
            <br>
            Duration: <%= diet.duration %> days.
            <br>
            Trainer: <%= diet.user.name %>
            <br>
            Cost: <%= diet.cost %>$
            <br>
          </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<%=diet.id%>" class="panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<%=diet.id%>">
      <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='<%= diet.introvid%>' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
         <div class="plans_subscribe"> 
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>






<% end %>

</div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <%= render 'shared/links' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I say, the exact same code works on heroku in the staging app within the pipeline, bit not when pushed to production. I have migrated DB.

Log shows the following:

```html
2016-08-05T19:34:45.767820+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:34:45.767817+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-08-05T19:34:45.767819+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2016-08-05T19:34:45.767822+00:00 app[web.1]:     32:             Cost: <%= diet.cost %>$
2016-08-05T19:34:45.767820+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:             Duration: <%= diet.duration %> days.
2016-08-05T19:34:45.767824+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-08-05T19:35:24.555153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/show_plans" host=www.myfitstat.com request_id=0e9ecc65-d9ba-4805-89af-802f804186e2 fwd="81.101.122.253" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=82ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-08-05T19:35:24.436197+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/show_plans" for 81.101.122.253 at 2016-08-05 20:35:24 +0100
2016-08-05T19:35:24.438213+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#show_plans as HTML
2016-08-05T19:35:24.440544+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mUser Load (1.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
2016-08-05T19:35:24.443086+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mGroup Load (1.3ms)[0m  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groups_users" ON "groups"."id" = "groups_users"."group_id" WHERE "groups_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
2016-08-05T19:35:24.444528+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_avatar.html.erb (0.5ms)
2016-08-05T19:35:24.446110+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mGroup Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups"  WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 6]]
2016-08-05T19:35:24.447802+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "weights"  WHERE "weights"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
2016-08-05T19:35:24.448169+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_user_info.html.erb (4.4ms)
2016-08-05T19:35:24.449524+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mDiet Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "diets".* FROM "diets"[0m
2016-08-05T19:35:24.512148+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/show_plans.html.erb within layouts/application (68.4ms)
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513300+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513301+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513301+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:             Duration: <%= diet.duration %> days.
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513302+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513302+00:00 app[web.1]:     30:             Trainer: <%= diet.user.name %>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513303+00:00 app[web.1]:     31:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513303+00:00 app[web.1]:     32:             Cost: <%= diet.cost %>$
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513304+00:00 app[web.1]:     33:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513304+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/home/show_plans.html.erb:30:in `block in _app_views_home_show_plans_html_erb___2816138431848340693_69990420277100'
2016-08-05T19:35:29.391085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.myfitstat.com request_id=4c0c4184-eea2-42a8-b6a0-500e85ccb9ec fwd="69.162.124.237" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=58ms status=200 bytes=778
2016-08-05T19:35:29.331354+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/" for 69.162.124.237 at 2016-08-05 20:35:29 +0100
2016-08-05T19:35:31.244915+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/users/sign_in" for 69.162.124.237 at 2016-08-05 20:35:31 +0100
2016-08-05T19:35:31.248854+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2016-08-05T19:35:31.595348+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.5ms)
2016-08-05T19:35:31.595414+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (342.3ms)
2016-08-05T19:35:31.609028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/users/sign_in" host=www.myfitstat.com request_id=dc1f95c4-50bd-422b-8070-8e196d612281 fwd="69.162.124.237" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=357ms status=200 bytes=778
```

Comment: Care to post the error or exception? might be in your `heroku logs`

Comment: Things that could be different are: 

 - compiled assets (run `rake assets:clean assets:precompile` then commit the new files and re-deploy)
 - environment variables (make sure `heroku config` is the same for both apps)
 - migrations and restart (sometimes the postgres cache is stale after migrating, so run `heroku restart` on both apps)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it really is appreciated.
Cleaned & precompiled assets then pushed & promoted again.  Staging works fine production still broken.

Added logs to original post.

Comment: please post more of the logs, I can't see the error it raised or the rest of the backtrace.

Comment: Sorry about that, not sure what I am looking for - pasted full log into original post

Just checked Heroku config for each app and only differences are for DB URL

Comment: Seems like it's a data issue `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method name for nil:NilClass)` ? Whatever you are calling .name on does not seem to exist.

Is your database the same in both environments? If this app is not in production use try pointing your production environment to your staging DB and see if it works with the staging data or just make sure whatever name is being called on actually exists.

Comment: Well not sure what was going on there - removed a few rows from DB and all is working well now!

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I dont think when you promote staging to production, it will run migrations. That may be the issue.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines#can-i-run-scripts-such-as-rake-db-migrate-when-promoting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with your data being different in Staging than in Production.  diet.user is nil in your production environment which is evident from the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513301+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513301+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:             Duration: <%= diet.duration %> days.
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513302+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513302+00:00 app[web.1]:     30:             Trainer: <%= diet.user.name %>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513303+00:00 app[web.1]:     31:             <br>
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513303+00:00 app[web.1]:     32:             Cost: <%= diet.cost %>$
2016-08-05T19:35:24.513304+00:00 app[web.1]:     33:             <br>
```

I would go into the DB and verify that there is a value for diet.user.

Answer (score 0):

try `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql --app your-app-name` since it seems like your db is not created by heroku